# YouTube Data API quota increase response as "User Experience - Playback Integrity" - Help Needed

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are using the YouTube Data API V3 and the allocated quota is very less.

After submitting the quota increment request, Google responded us saying that the application is not following one of their terms which is :

Policy F.3 (User Experience - Playback Integrity)

But we are not violating any of the mentioned points. Can some one suggest us to get our quota increased.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to submit the request again **after** you stop violating this [Policy F.3 (User Experience - Playback Integrity)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#f-user-experience).

You may not think you are violating it but google thinks you are and its them you have to please or you are not going to get your quota increase I suggest you look though your application again.

> Playback Integrity
>
> Playback integrity refers to the ability to determine and measure how
>   content and ads are served, how video playback is initiated and
>   implemented, and how users interact with YouTube features in your API
>   Client. Playback integrity is critical to the YouTube platform, as it
>   helps protect creators' interests, including their ability to monetize
>   their content and develop their audience.
>
> YouTube believes that playback integrity is contingent on a user
>   choosing to watch a video, and API Clients are prohibited from
>   providing incentives for watching videos as follows:
>
> API Clients must not charge users to watch content in an embedded
>   YouTube player.
>
> 1. API Clients must not otherwise gate access to a video by requiring a
>      user to take an action other than clicking the play button to view or
>      continue playing YouTube audiovisual content. For example, API Clients
>      must not require a user to subscribe to a channel or like a video to
>      continue watching YouTube audiovisual content.
> 2. For clarity, if your API Client's normal functionality requires a
>      certain action that is not specific to YouTube API Services, such as
>      login or age verification, that functionality is allowed.
> 3. API Clients must not offer or provide incentives, rewards, or other
>      compensation to users for engaging with YouTube Applications (directly
>      or indirectly) by performing actions like viewing content, liking
>      content, sharing content, subscribing to channels, adding comments.
>      For example, API Clients must not offer features or services that
>      trade video views for a fee or that trade video views in return for
>      other YouTube-related or non-YouTube-related actions.

If you are uncertain how you are violating the policy, explain why to tech support and request they reevaluate.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. We have submitted the request form again stating the business we are doing and the way we are using YouTube API. Lets see how they will respond.

Comment: @AnilKumarMysa Hi. Could you please share your experience? Have you get your quota increased?